# Highly Skewed Binary Response Variable 10% One Category, 90% Other

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution

I have a highly skewed binary response variable in my dataset. I am having issues finding a model that meets all assumptions for a binomial distribution GLM, and I believe this may be correlated to this skewed response. Should I use a resampling method?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What assumptions do you see as violated?

Comment: Why is 10%-90% *highly skewed*? Sounds pretty good to me. Logistic models only begin to lose accuracy at much higher extremes...like 1%-99% and rarer.

Comment: What assumptions do you think are violated in particular?

Comment: AFAIK, the only assumption of a binomial regression is that the response variable is binomially distributed conditional on the explanatory variables.

Comment: The idea that disrespecting the observed data by molesting it would improve anything is quite hard to understand.